# Newtonsoft.Json serialization of PagedList<T> is not including some properties

Tags: json, json.net, pagedlist

I am trying to serialize a PagedList object ( https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging/blob/master/src/MvcPaging/PagedList.cs ) to Json, like this:

```
PagedList<Product> pagedList = new PagedList<Product>(products, (page - 1), pageSize);
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pagedList);
```

If I use the above code, in the result I get an array of Product objects serialized properly. However the properties below (of PagedList) are not being included in the Json result:

```
    public bool HasNextPage { get; }
    public bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
    public bool IsFirstPage { get; }
    public bool IsLastPage { get; }
    public int ItemEnd { get; }
    public int ItemStart { get; }
    public int PageCount { get; }
    public int PageIndex { get; }
    public int PageNumber { get; }
    public int PageSize { get; }
    public int TotalItemCount { get; }
```

They are not being serialized but they are part of PagedList.

Does anyone know why? And how could I include those properties in the serialization?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The serializer sees that PagedList is enumerable, so it serializes it to a JavaScript array. To make this easier to deal with I expose a `GetMetaData()` function on the PagedList object that will return a MetaData object containing exactly the fields you mentioned above. This means you can serialize your pagedlist like so:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{
  items = pagedList,
  metaData = pagedList.GetMetaData()
});
```

This should result in a JSON object like so:

```
{
    "Items": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ],
    "MetaData": {
        "PageSize": 1,
        "PageCount": 2,
        "HasNextPage": true,
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea how to deserialize

Comment: Thank you Troy, very nice implementation. I just add the deserialization part  as AMH asked.

Answer (score 0):

there is a jquery plugin which is used to excitely to do this :

https://github.com/turhancoskun/pagify.mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#users').pagify({
        dataUrl: '/User/UserLis',
        callBack: function(){
           // Ajax remove preloader and some other callbacks  
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
           // Ajax show preloader and some other function before start
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

readme.md file contains an example

Answer (score 0):

To serialize, just use the Troy's implementation. But to deserialize create 2 new classes:

```
public class PaginationEntity<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
    public PaginationEntity()
    {
        Items = new List<TEntity>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Items { get; set; }
    public PaginationMetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}

public class PaginationMetaData
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int FirstItemOnPage { get; set; }
    public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }
    public bool HasPreviousPage { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirstPage { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastPage { get; set; }
    public int LastItemOnPage { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize this way:

```
PaginationEntity<TEntity> listPaginated = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaginationEntity<TEntity>>(json)
```

and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

By default asp.core uses DataContractSerializer, so anyone could set `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` to Product class and members and get needed data with following action:

```
 public IActionResult Products(int page=1,int countPerPage=10)
    {
        var result = _dbContext.Products.AsNoTracking().ToPagedList(page, countPerPage);

        return Ok( new{result, total=result.TotalItemCount });
    }
```

with no need to use Newtonsoft.Json